# Connect to TCP clients Elixir

Tags: erlang, elixir

Trying to connect to a TCP server, send a command and get a response.

I've got something like this in Ruby

```
TCPSocket.open("127.0.0.1", 3344)
 s.send(JSON.dump({"id" => 1, "method" => "Responder.Status", "params" => [""]}),0)
```

Any pointer to any documentation/library that would enable achieve something like that(or more robust) in Elixir?

Comment: http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_tcp.html http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/task-and-gen-tcp.html

Comment: Thanks @Dogbert,  please i've updated my question.  Any help in how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For TCP connections, the erlang standard library [gen_tcp](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_tcp.html) can be used:

```
{:ok, socket} = :gen_tcp.connect('localhost', 6379, [:binary])
data = {"id" => 1, "method" => "Responder.Status", "params" => [""]}
:ok = :gen_tcp.send(socket, Poison.encode!(data))
:ok = :gen_tcp.close(socket)
```

Comment: Thank you. Updated my question.  How would I achieve something like that.  Tried Poison.encode , but got an error...

Comment: `gen_tcp.send(socket, Poison.encode(%{id: 1, method: "Responder.Status"}) |> elem(1))` should work.

Comment: or just like the OP of the reply suggested use Poison.encode!